# Unknowingly joined scam tech company in the past. Should I include it in my work history for a background check?

Tags: work-experience, careers, background-check

A little background. My background is not a tech. I decided to join tech after self studying.

When I was working at a non tech company as a non tech position, I was offered a job from one of those scam tech companies, which I had no idea back then. It was just a phone interview and they told me they would hire me. (which I should have known, but I was desperate to find a tech job). So, I took the job and left my first company.

In case you don't know about them, this scam tech company is one of those companies that tell people that they will train them, but after you are trained, they fake your resume with let say 5-6 years of experience and send it to different companies and they take portion of your contract wages.

After finding that out, I got out from there. More precisely, I finished the training and left. I believe I "worked" there (yes, I did get paid while getting trained) for about 4 months or so.

After that I got hired for legitimate contract to hire position and it has been about 2 years that turned into the full time position. In total 2 and 3 months as a current position including contract period.

Then I decided to move up my career and I was recently offered a verbal job confirmation from a major tech company.

I'm just wondering, should I include the scam company as part of my work history. I did put that as part of my resume saying "confidential consulting company".

My coworkers who know about the situations told me to not even provide it. But I'm wondering what will happen. Especially I have about 8 months gap if I don't show that as part of my work history from non-tech to tech.

I really don't want to miss this opportunity because working for FANG has always been my dream. Should I put it as my work history when I file my paperwork and not mention anything about it? I do believe I still retain a W2 from that company. So was wondering if I do provide my W2, they might not contact that company. But that company turned out to be quite known on the internet as a scam tech.

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be implying that you're somehow culpable for the scam simply because you worked there. Were you aware of, and did you knowingly participate in the scam?

Comment: Well, I didn't participate. But I did realized that during the middle. But I chose to stay until they provided all the training. At that time I felt like, "well this company got me leaving the current job without explaining this going on, so I'll also take some advantages from it"...

Comment: But no, I left because I was very uncomfortable when they were trying to post my resume.

Comment: Well... it kind of sounds like you knowingly participated in the scam. You discovered it at some point in your employment but you chose to go along with it because you wanted to extract some benefit for yourself. That's a tricky situation. I'm not sure what you should do. I'm a proponent of being completely honest in all matters... so I don't think you should try to hide it, omit it, or lie about it... but being completely honest may put this opportunity at risk.

Comment: Yes. My guts say so too. I agree that honesty is what matters. But whether do I regret that "extracting benefit" part? No. I think I deserved it. Was I naive? Yes.

Comment: Wait a second. You have a _verbal_ job offer and are only now wondering what to write on your CV? This doesn’t add up.

Comment: Omit that job from your CV, if possible. It was your first "tech" job and you have a plausible cover by saying you were transitioning out of the non-tech career into the tech career over a span of 4 months more than 2 years ago. You did nothing wrong and were in a vulnerable position when you stayed to complete that "training".

Comment: We need some clarification on where in the hiring process you are, what you're worried about, and what you're being asked for from the new employer. Per @Gaius's comment, this doesn't add up. You've already received a job offer, but you're asking about including this in your resume (which the new employer presumably has already seen, if they've made an offer). Are you somehow worried about losing this offer? Or are you worried about future offers? And you also mention W2s from your old employer, and talk about providing those - why on earth would you give someone a W2 from an old employer?

Comment: Would you be able to claim that period as study, given that is what you did there?
Have you already send your resume with this period as work experience?

Comment: https://www.stilt.com/blog/2018/01/dirty-truth-desi-consulting-companies/

is this type of company you are talking about?

Comment: FANG?   Fitbit-Accessorized Networking Group?

Comment: @April Facebook-Amazon-Netflix-Google. None of those companies are known for making verbal job offers before even seeing a candidate’s CV. Like I said before, this doesn’t add up.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Can I omit a job from the employment history on my background check?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/82794/can-i-omit-a-job-from-the-employment-history-on-my-background-check)

Answer (score 3):

To me it sounds like you weren't really part of the scam. If I understand correctly all you did for that scam company was finish their training and then leave. So you never worked via them for some other company meaning you never made the scam company money, you only costed money (since you were being paid during training)

I would probably leave it out of your resume but answer truthfully when asked about it. All it shows is some poor judgement on your part when you took the scam job and good judgement when you left before really participating in the scam.